# Migrate from JBoss 4.0.5 to 5x

Tags: jboss, xml-parsing, xerces

What would be the best way to detect a library (jar file) that is invoking an old "Xerces XML Parser" conflicting this same library provided by JBoss 5.x.

The reason is that today I'm trying to migrate from JBoss 4.0.5GA to any JBoss version except 4.x family.

Stacktrace follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might be helpful to get a tattletale report and JDR report as well.
https://tattletale.jboss.org

Tattletale is useful to find missing classes from the classpath or class/package with multiple location.

Good luck